# How to make appearance of jssor slide a triggerable event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, jssor

Using a basic JSSOR Slideshow, with *n* div image placeholders, where the divs are read in descending or top-down order, just like any other normal HTML page, I can add javascript into a div, or add javascript somewhere else on the page to make something happen within a slide div (animation, fade, etc.).

The problem is it will trigger once, as when the document is loaded. How do I make a javascript function "re-triggerable", so that it is called when that one slide (let's say slide #2) appears in the display loop?

Feel free to ask more questions if this is not clear enough.

Here's an example: [Slide Show](http://webanautics.com/slideshow/)  On the first slide appearance, a gold medal scrolls to the middle of the slide, using jQuery animate(). It will only do this once, not each time the slide appears. The reason is that the gold medal animate script only loads once, when the html page is loaded. I want that gold medal animate script to reload again and again, each time slide #1 makes its appearance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please do this job when slideshow plays over at slide 0.

```
        var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$(...;

        function SlideshowEndEventHandler(slideIndex, progressBegin, slideshowBegin, slideshowEnd, progressEnd) {
            if (slideIndex == 0) {
                //runs the animation when slideshow plays over at slide 0

                $("#goldmedal").animate({
                    opacity: 0.99,
                    left: "+=490",
                    height: "toggle"
                }, 2500, function () {
                    // Animation complete.
                    $("#goldmedal").animate({ opacity: 0.0 }, 4000, function () {
                        $("#goldmedal").css("left", "0px");
                    });
                });
            }
        }

        jssor_slider1.$On($JssorSlider$.$EVT_SLIDESHOW_END, SlideshowEndEventHandler);


        //As it would not play slideshow at the beginning for slide 0, make a manual trigger at the beginning then.
        SlideshowEndEventHandler(0);
```